# Find two elements x,y in P(A) such that $xy=0, x\ne0$ and $ y\ne0$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

The question is as follows:

Let $A = \{a, b\}$ and list the four elements of the power set $P (A)$. We consider the operations $+$ to be $\cap$, · to be $\cup$, and complement to be set complement. Consider $1$ to be A and 0 to be $\phi$.

Find two elements $x,y$ in $P(A)$ such that $xy=0$, $x\ne0$ and $y\ne0$.

I understood that $P(A) = \{\{a,b\}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \phi\}$

I didn't understand what specifically the question is asking as well as how to go about solving it. Any clarity/help with the solution would be much appreciated.

Would the solution be as simple as $x = a, y = b$?

Comment: Nearly. But $a \notin P(A)$, since $P(A)$ contains *subsets* of $A$, not *elements* of $A$. But $\{a\} \in P(A)$ and $\{b\} \in P(A)$..

Answer (score 0):

the question is asking to find $x,y\in P(A)$ such that $x,y\neq \emptyset $ and $x\cap y=\emptyset$. So, your guess is true.